# dynamic Drodown in html

Tags: javascript, forms, dropdown

I have to make a html page in which there should be TextBox and a add Button and if user add something via Textbox then it should be visible in Dropdown.

kindly help with code.

thanks in advance.

Comment: what you have tried so far? We can not write code for you.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You need to create a minimal reproducible example and mention what you tried to sort the problem so that people can answer better.

Comment: can you work with React? you can make a component and every time you click to the button create a new <option></option> inside the <select></select> inside the dropdown bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you need but based on your description, I was able to build this basic page:

```js
const list = document.getElementById("lists");
const text = document.getElementById("myText");
function addEntry(){
  var newOption = document.createElement("OPTION");
  newOption.value = text.value;
  newOption.innerHTML = text.value;
  list.appendChild(newOption);
  text.value = "";
  text.focus();
}
```

```html
<select id="lists">
<option selected disabled>-- SELECT ONE --</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="myText" placeholder="Type here...">
<input type="button" onclick="addEntry()" value="+ ADD">
```

Basically, this uses a function that takes the value, creates an HTML `<option>` element, then inserts it into the dropdown menu.